# What is the significance of the median eigenvalue of a graph Laplacian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

When I look at the spectral density plots of my (usual) Laplacian graphs, they spike at the median eigenvalue. But what significance for the graph/matrix (which originates from a network) does the median eigenvalue hold? Are there any generalizations that can be made about the median eigenvalue?

Googling "median eigenvalue" turns up work by Bohar, which is quite opaque and focused specifically on molecular orbits. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Laplacian graph or graph Laplacian?